# How to update the latest workbox version when using Vue CLI

Tags: vue.js, webpack, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am using Vue CLI plugin - @vue/cli-plugin-pwa and Google workbox to build a PWA app. I want to use the latest version of the workbox which is **5.1.2** however, when I use the workbox (webpack) plugin to generate *service-worker.js* file, it only contains the **4.3.1** version as below then I run build script:

```
importScripts("/precache-manifest.83bfba368ee78b40421bed00a145f5e0.js", "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

//etc
```

Is there any way to configure to get the latest version when I bundle, for now, I need to modify manually.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution (test), use the ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin plugin, then it worked, simple yet effective.

```js
new ReplaceInFileWebpackPlugin([
  {
    dir: "dist",
    files: ["service-worker.js"],
    rules: [
      {
        search: "releases/4.3.1",
        replace: "releases/5.1.2",
      },
    ],
  },
]),
```